# Replacing An Element in a Python List Using Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two items: a list of country codes as 2-character strings, and a dictionary that maps each string to a value. I'd like to iterate through the list and change each element to its corresponding value. Trying the method below:

```
countryList = kData['country'].tolist()
for i in countryList:
    i = countryCodes[i]
    print(i)

print(countryList)
```

Results in the following output:

```
75
234
39
['FR', 'GB', 'CA']
```

When I want the output to be:

```
75
234
39
[75, 234, 39]
```

Even though I'm setting each of element in the list and verifying that it HAS been changed by printing it, when I print the list as a whole the changes haven't carried over. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You never modify `countryList`

Comment: And you shouldn't modify countryList because you are iterating through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in countryList:
    i = countryCodes[i]
```

should change to

```
for index, val in enumerate(countryList):
    countryList[index] = countryCodes[val]
```

Because when you iterate an list through `for i in countryList`, the `i` is another variable, when you assign `i` to new value, the content of contryList remains unchanged, you need to use `contryList[index] = val` to make list change

Answer (score 3):

You are only changing what the variable `i` refers to.

Better you create a new list:

```
countryList = kData['country'].tolist()

newList = []

for i in countryList:
    newList.append(countryCodes[i])
    print(i)

countryList = newList

print(countryList)
```

This can be written shorter but I don't want to confuse you.